# What is the best way to iterate all data?

Tags: java

I have 2.6 million rows and I would like to limit 20000 rows each iteration.

Here is simple code:

```
int limit_size=200000;
int rowCount=getrowCount();
startPoint=0;
endPoint=limit_size;

while
 getData(startPoint,endPoint)
 startPoint=endPoint+1;
 endPoint=endPoint+limit_size
```

What is the way to iterate all data 0 to 2.6 million?

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible: a simple loop through any collection or element-by-element loading will limit the size of your iteration to 1, which is small enough. You want to do anything on chunks of data you need to describe that

Comment: Is that ..Groovy or something?  It does not look like standard Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (<DataType> d : data) { ... }
```

or,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2600000; i++) { ... }
```

where ... is the code you are putting within the loop

Answer (score 1):

Generally you'd have a loop inside a loop.  The outer loop would be a while loop -- while N < array size -- and the inner loop would start at a N and increment that until N >= oldN + 20000 (or greater than array size).

Answer (score 0):

```
int limit_size=200000;
int rowCount=getrowCount();
startPoint=0;
endPoint=limit_size;

while (startPoint < rowCount)
{
  if (endpoint > rowCount)
    endpoint = rowCount;
  getData(startPoint,endPoint)
  startPoint=endPoint+1;
  endPoint=endPoint+limit_size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers are correct but you can consider the Iterator which is, for huge array, faster. I did some test in the past: you can find a compact resume here

http://www.slideshare.net/venergiac/advanced-java-23714810

slide 11.